# How to make a section show all the content? (in a UITableView)

Tags: uitableview

I am playing with a piece of code and this is what I have gotten so far. The app gets an XML feed to display job advertisements, and shows them as in the images I attached.

What I am trying to figure out is, how to make the "Description" part display all the information taken from the XML file.

Would the answer be hidden in changing something in this method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch(indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
        cell.text = aBook.title;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.text = aBook.author;
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.text = aBook.summary;
        break;
}

return cell;
```

}

[image: List of jobs]

[image: Detail of the job]

Comment: As a "meta-comment", you might want to find a newer example to work with.  Assigning to `cell.text` was deprecated three years ago.

Comment: Can you give further explanation. I don't understand if you want to display the information in one cell or just only diplay the informations without any tableView

Comment: @Hosni As you could see, the 3rd section, the "Description" is not displaying all the information, it is truncated and displaying just whatever fits to the first and the only line for that section.

Comment: Use cell.label.text or cell.textLabel instead of cell.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement this:

```
-(CGFloat ) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
If(indexPath.section==2)
{
return 60;
}
}
```

Comment: I should add this new method in the same .m file, right? But it is telling me "Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?"

Comment: yes i meant NSIndexPath there was a mistake i corrected it it's `(NSIndexPath*)` and yes you should add it to your code with all the other delegate methods of the tableView.